# Triple screen on MBP 2016 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I currently own a MBP (2016, 13", No Touch Bar) as well as an official Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (HDMI version). I have a second screen plugged in (Asus VS247H, HDMI, 24" 1080p), and everything works OK.

I was wondering if I could buy another identical adapter to plug a third screen (same as the second) and then have a triple screen setup : MBP screen + 2 external monitors ?
I would like to avoid buying another 80€ adapter if it will not work. In such case, would anyone know of a viable solution for achieving this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this model MBP supports two external displays without any problems, up to 4K each, or a single display at 5K. In both cases the MBP's built-in screen can also be used simultaneously.

You *may* want to consider whether buying another identical adapter is the best way to go, as you may want the flexibility of using another adapter or dock that provides other connection options as well. However, you can certainly achieve what you want and keep your MBP on charge as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have found posts online going both ways about this. About the flexibility I agree that a dock would be more efficient, but I have found none that offer me two standard video outputs (meaning HDMI, DVI, or standard DP) while keeping a single connection with the MBP