# Triple external monitor on 13" Macbook Pro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've recently been given a 13" Macbook Pro 2018 by work so that I can work from home. Just to note I am completely new to MacOS, but have a lot of sysadmin experience on other platforms.

I have a triple monitor set up with my Windows PC and I was hoping to use this with the new Macbook. But I looked online and it seems that this model is officially limited to two external monitors. However The limit is for two 4k monitors, and I want three 1080p which is a lower total pixel count than even one 4k screen so the MBP definitely has the power required for this.

Also I don't need the built-in display as the MBP will be tucked away. Clearly the MBP *can* do three displays if we include the built-in one, so is there a way to redirect that to an external screen? Is there an official or unofficial way to make this work? Would using a thunderbolt based adapter allow more bandwidth so more screens? I've seen reports of USB3 (not type C) display adapters that can bypass this restriction. Or there's this https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay that would involve using a Raspberry Pi as an airplay receiver and using that as the third screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you already have the hardware, why not start connecting things? You can read up on closed clamshell mode and supported configurations and know often things run fine at lower refresh rates and “support” means full speed, not that you get no signal.

Comment: And if people down vote this, I would edit out all the side questions, reasoning and hunches and stick to specific interfaces. Sometimes people are prickly with votes on hardware connections.

Comment: I have a handful of USB C to HDMI adapters, I tried them but I could only get two external displays going, the last one I connected was always showing no signal.

Comment: Setting aside the current beast of a Mac Pro, the iMac Pro and 2013 Mac Pro all do 6 displays easy. It depends on how precisely you connect them in my experience - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207443 - hopefully 3+1 isn’t too much for your MacBook Pro. [The OS can handle it, but the GPU is where you might need a Thunderbolt dock or eGPU to rock three external displays if you can’t swing adapters that work out of the box](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/297180/5472)